# Bitbucket private server REST API

Tags: rest, api, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I can't find any documentation regarding bitbucket API when hosted on private server. 
Official one: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html
We have hosted bitbucket server and simply changing the host doesn't work, it looks like the whole API is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> simply changing the host doesn't work, it looks like the whole API is different.

I have no idea why that would be, but it seems that you're right. There are different API docs for Bitbucket Cloud (which you have found) and for [Bitbucket Server](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/command-line-rest.html).

These APIs are certainly different:

- Bitbucket Cloud has a number of [changesets endpoints](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/changesets-resource-296095208.html), e.g.

  ```
  GET https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/
      changesets?limit=integer?start=node
  ```
- Bitbucket Server has no `changesets` endpoints at all, though it *does* have some `changes` endpoints

Comment: From what I understand, Bitbucket Server and Bitbucket (Cloud) are two entirely separate products that Atlassian is marketing under the same name, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket.